# MVC StackOverflowException with larger html data

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack, dom

I have the following method (i'm using the htmlagilitypack):

```
public DataTable tableIntoTable(HtmlDocument doc)
    {
        var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");
        var table = new DataTable("MyTable");
        table.Columns.Add("raw", typeof(string));                       

        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            if (
                (!node.InnerHtml.Contains("pldefault"))
                && (!node.InnerHtml.Contains("ntdefault"))
                && (!node.InnerHtml.Contains("bgtabon"))                
                )
            {
                table.Rows.Add(node.InnerHtml);
            }
        }
        return table;
    }
```

It accepts html grabbed using this:

```
 public HtmlDocument getDataWithGet(string url)
    {
        using (var wb = new WebClient())
        {
            string response = wb.DownloadString(url);
            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(response);
            return doc;
        }
    }
```

All works fine with an html document that is 3294 lines long.
When I feed it some html that is 33960 lines long I get:
StackOverflowException was unhandled at the IF statement in the tableIntoTable method as seen in this image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgZqd.jpg

I thought it might be related to the MaxHttpCollectionKeys limit of 1000 so I tried putting this in my Web.config and it still doesn't work:
add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="9999"

I'm not really sure where to go from here, it only breaks with larger html documents.

Comment: Why don't you use xpath to query node content?

Comment: Isn't that what:
`var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");`
is doing?

Comment: your query is bad you could use a more proper one, but about the exception try to increase your stack size using editbin.exe and it will probably work , to 1MB at least

Comment: @jrow And then you're looking over each node to get all content and perform a String.Contains operation. I don't know how can this cause a stack overflow (you may post stack trace for further investigation) but using xpath ALSO for that is  faster and less resources consuming.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to select all the tables, the html source i'm pulling from has no table ids or anyway to distinguish between them ( i have no control over the source html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the values in your if statement are contained in some attribute value of some decendant of a table.

```
var xpath = @"//table[not(.//*[contains(@*,'pldefault') or
                               contains(@*,'ntdefault') or 
                               contains(@*,'bgtabon')])]";

var tables = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath);
```

**Upadte:** More accurately based on your comments:

```
        @"//table[not(.//td[contains(@class,'pldefault') or
                            contains(@class,'ntdefault') or 
                            contains(@class,'bgtabon')])]";
```

Comment: This worked.  Is it because it's only selecting the things I want and maybe that's a less amount?  (pldefault, nedefault and bgtabon are tables I don't want)

Comment: @Jrow but what are they exactly attributes in the table tag or attributes of the descendant of the table tag, sharing more info about your html would help i wrote this answer without knowing what you want exactly.

Comment: It's the class of TD's inside the tables that I don't need:
`<TD CLASS="pldefault">`
There are a ton of tables, some of the tables with data that I don't need contain TD's with the classes pldefault, ntdefault and bgtabon.  The other tables have no classes or ID's or anything, just simply `<TABLE>`
I tried to put the html into pastebin but it's too large.

Comment: @Jrow ah great then this query is for you.